# what should be done first, handling missing data or finding correlation between features and drop irrelevant features?

Tags: correlation, data-preprocessing

In data science, Which process should come first, handling missing data or 
finding correlation between features. I am asking this question because I have problem in following cases:

**1) Handling Missing data first, then finding correlation between columns** - We have wasted much time preparing some columns, handling missing data. Because, if we are going to delete any column, what is use of filling null data.

**2) finding correlation between columns first, then handling missing data** - 
it would be difficult to find correlation between two columns if some data is missing. it might give wrong or biased result.

Comment: What a great question.  I think the magnitude of the missingness should determine your course.  If a variable is missing 3% of its data points, addressing that can likely be merely a "tidying-up operation" after looking into relationships and deciding what models to build.  If missingness is at 30%, you wouldn't want to trust any relationships you found until you did the best job of imputation that you could.  That assumes data are missing at random (MAR), or completely at random (MCAR).

Comment: @rolando2 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less the same answer as to your similar question [what should be done first, handling missing data or dealing with data types?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/428142/what-should-be-done-first-handling-missing-data-or-dealing-with-data-types),  first handle the data, do the imputation, and only then estimate correlations.

But as the comment by @rolando2 says, the amount of missingness could be important. If the percent missingness in a variable is to high, it is difficult to trust any results based on imputation. In such cases, at least use multiple imputation, and then you can see how much variation there is (in this case, in the estimated correlations) due to imputation.